# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'CA3' to data type int

Tags: sql, type-conversion, int, varchar

Hello I am receiving the error in the title. The problem arises because the original datatype is varchar. I am having trouble converting the fields
'CA_Admitted_TG' and 'Prev_CA_Admitted_TG' into varchar. 
Where in all this code do I make the change?
I have tried converting them in the declare statements.

```
     Declare @UWD table
        (RB_IND varchar(30)
        ,CY_Eff_Yr_Mnth varchar(7)
        ,CY_Eff_Prior_3Mnth_Ind varchar(1)
        ,Tier_Grp int
        ,NB_WP money
        ,RB_WP money
        ,NB_MP money
        ,RB_MP money
        ,Expired_WP money
        ,RB_Prev_WP money
        ,RB_Prev_MP money
        ,NB_Pol_Cnt int
        ,RB_Pol_Cnt int
        ,Expired_Pol_Cnt int)
    insert into @UWD
    Select case when NB_IND = 'CN' then Prev_RB_IND
                else RB_Ind
            End
            ,case when NB_IND = 'CN' then PY_Exp_Yr_Mnth
                else CY_Eff_Yr_Mnth
            End 
            , Case when NB_IND = 'CN' then PY_Exp_Prior_3mnth_Ind
                else CY_Eff_Prior_3Mnth_Ind
              End 
            , Case when NB_IND = 'CN' then Prev_CA_Admitted_TG
                else CA_Admitted_TG
              End
            , sum(case when NB_Ind = 'NB' then WrittenPrem else 0 end)
            , sum(case when NB_Ind = 'RB' then WrittenPrem else 0 end)

            , sum(case when NB_Ind = 'NB' then ManualPrem else 0 end) 
            , sum(case when NB_Ind = 'RB' then ManualPrem else 0 end) 

            , sum(case when NB_Ind = 'RB' then WrittenPrem
                    when NB_IND = 'CN' then Prev_WrittenPrem
                    else 0 end) 
            , sum(case when NB_Ind = 'RB' then Prev_WrittenPrem else 0 end) 
            , sum(case when NB_Ind = 'RB' then Prev_ManualPrem else 0 end) 
            , sum(case when NB_IND='NB' then 1 else 0 end) 
            , sum(case when NB_IND='RB' then 1 else 0 end) 
            , sum(case when NB_Ind <> 'NB' then 1 else 0 end) 
    From dbo.EPLI_Tracking_Rpt_Data 
    where NB_Ind in ('RB', 'NB', 'CN') 
        and ((case when NB_IND = 'CN' then Prev_RB_IND
                else RB_Ind
            End) = 'CA Admitted')
    group by (case when NB_IND = 'CN' then Prev_RB_IND
                else RB_Ind
            End)
            ,(case when NB_IND = 'CN' then PY_Exp_Yr_Mnth
                else CY_Eff_Yr_Mnth
            End) 
            ,(Case when NB_IND = 'CN' then PY_Exp_Prior_3mnth_Ind
                else CY_Eff_Prior_3Mnth_Ind
             End)
            ,(Case when NB_IND = 'CN' then Prev_CA_Admitted_TG
                else CA_Admitted_TG
              End)

    Declare @CN table
        (Prev_RB_IND varchar(30)
        ,PY_Exp_Yr_Mnth varchar(7)
        ,PY_Exp_Prior_3Mnth_Ind varchar(1)
        ,CN_qt_TG int
        ,CN_qt_WP money
        ,CN_qt_MP money
        ,CN_expired_WP money
        ,CN_expired_MP money)
    Insert into @CN
    select a.Prev_RB_INd
        ,a.PY_Exp_Yr_Mnth
        ,a.PY_Exp_Prior_3mnth_Ind
        ,b.CA_Admitted_TG
        ,sum(b.quotedprem) as CN_qt_WP
        ,sum(b.Quoted_ManualPrem) as CN_qt_MP
        ,sum(a.Prev_WrittenPrem) 
        ,sum(a.Prev_ManualPrem)
    from dbo.EPLI_Tracking_Rpt_Data a
        inner join dbo.EPLI_Tracking_Rpt_SQB_RB b
            on a.prev_Pol_Num = b.prevpolicynum
        where a.NB_IND='CN' and b.Quoted = 1 and b.Bound = 0 and  a.Prev_RB_INd ='CA Admitted'
        group by a.Prev_RB_INd
                ,a.PY_Exp_Yr_Mnth
                ,a.PY_Exp_Prior_3mnth_Ind
                ,b.CA_Admitted_TG


    Select RB_IND
        , CY_Eff_Yr_Mnth
        , CY_Eff_Prior_3Mnth_Ind
        , Tier_Grp
        , NB_WP as NB_Prem
        , RB_WP as RB_Prem
        , NB_MP as NB_ManualPrem
        , RB_MP as RB_ManualPrem
        , Expired_WP as Expired_Prem
        , RB_Prev_WP as Prev_WrittenPrem
        , RB_Prev_MP as Prev_ManualPrem
        , NB_Pol_Cnt 
        , RB_Pol_Cnt 
        , Expired_Pol_Cnt 
        , b.Prev_RB_IND
        , b.PY_Exp_Yr_Mnth
        , b.PY_Exp_Prior_3mnth_Ind
        , b.CN_qt_TG
        , CN_qt_WP
        , CN_qt_MP 
        , CN_expired_WP 
        , CN_expired_MP 
    from @UWD a
        full join @CN b
            on a.RB_IND = b.Prev_RB_IND
                and a.CY_Eff_Yr_Mnth = b.PY_Exp_Yr_Mnth
                and a.CY_Eff_Prior_3Mnth_Ind = b.PY_Exp_Prior_3Mnth_Ind
                and a.Tier_Grp = b.CN_qt_TG
```

Comment: which column in your db contains "CA3"? Where in your code do you attempt to convert it to a number?

Comment: 'CA_Admitted_TG' and 'Prev_CA_Admitted_TG', they are both varchar(4) in the db. I want to keep it as varchar(4). So everywhere they appear in the code above, I've replace with cast(.... as varchar(4)). It's giving me the same error

Comment: If they are both varchar and contain non numerical data, why do you consistently declare INT type columns to hold them on your table variable ? Everything you've declared as int you're trying to stuff character data into, giving rise to this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Declare  @UWD table

```
,Tier_Grp int
```

into

```
,Tier_Grp varchar(4)
```

And change the Declare @CN table

```
,CN_qt_TG int
```

into

```
,CN_qt_TG varchar(4)
```

Comment: In the same column where "CA3" appears "NULL" can also appear. I now receive the following:Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'NULL' to data type int.

Comment: See amended change above.  The conversion error may be happening when the comparison is made.

Comment: Okay that seemed to work. Thank you. I'll continue to test it